# the file format and extension doesn't match excel asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, excel

I'm able to create excel file and download it with source from database. Everything is OK until i open it. It says exactly that what I have in title. I googled it and found on stackoverflow that I must add

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Additions.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
```

So I added them in my code but result is same. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my whole controller

```
        [Download]
        [Autorization(RoleTypes.AdminAndViewer)]
        public ActionResult DownloadAdditivesHistoryReport(DateTime from, DateTime to, int groupId)
        {
            try
            {
                //correct search datetime
                from = CorrectFormat.FDateTime.GetFromDate(from);
                to = CorrectFormat.FDateTime.GetToDate(to);


                float? rate = Settings.Core.Web.UI.Reports.Rate;
                float? netAmount = Settings.Core.Web.UI.Reports.NetAmount;

                List<AdditionReport_Result> AdditionReports = Uow.AdditionReport(to, groupId, rate, netAmount);

                //total results
                int totalResults = AdditionReports.Count();



                //fill model
                AdditivesHistoryItemModel[] model = AdditionReports
                        .Select(x => new AdditivesHistoryItemModel()
                        {
                            //Id = x.additionUserId,
                            GroupName = x.Branch,
                            RegistratorDisplayName = x.RegistratorUserName,
                            RegistratorName = x.Registrator,
                            Registrations = x.Registrations,
                            Fee = x.Fee,
                            NetAmount = x.NetAmount
                        }).ToArray();

                DataSet ds = AdditionHistoryForm.GetData(model);
                XPathDocument input = AdditionHistoryForm.GetDocument(ds);

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Core/Files/Additions.xls")))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Core/Files/Additions.xls"));

                using (FileStream output = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Core/Files/Additions.xls"), FileMode.CreateNew))
                {
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Additions.xls");
                    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

                    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
                    xslt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Core/Files/AdditionHistory.xslt"));
                    xslt.Transform(input, null, output);


                }


                //create xlsx file name
                string fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), CurrentUser.Id);



                return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes((Server.MapPath("~/Core/Files/Additions.xls"))), "application/vnd.ms-excel", String.Format("{0}.xml", fileName));               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log error
                EventLogger.Logger.WriteEcxeption(ex);

                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the file extension is `.xls` and not `.xlsx`?

Comment: @ic3man7019 yes it's .xls

Comment: What fileformat are you really creating? xls, xlsx, csv, txt, other?

Comment: @jkpieterse xls. actually I dont care which format it will. simply i want to let user download excel file

Comment: @jkpieterse I said. XLS

Comment: I know you said that, but given that Excel complains about the format something must be wrong. The error message Excel shows, indicates that the file format of your file does not match the content of the file.

Comment: @gsiradze Did you have a solution to this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @Dashamlav no idea tbh. It's been a long time